# Proper way to use lib folder in a JAR

Tags: java, windows, jar, compilation, executable

I'm facing a probably trivial problem, but I believe it is easiest to use the help of the community:

I have the following project in my jar:

```
com (output of my compiled code)
lib/a.jar
    b.jar
    ... (about 30 more)
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Content of MANIFEST.MF below:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/*
Main-Class: com.irrelevant.MyMainclass
```

**I keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError -s.**

Obviously, the missing class is part of one of the jars in the lib folder.

It's worth pointing out that I've been executing this jar properly before when I extracted the content of the referenced jars. So everything works fine. I just want to use the jars instead of extracting their contents.

The goal is to be able to run the application by simply calling:

**java -jar myjar.jar**

Again, I was able to execute this when I was using extracted contents of the references jars.

```
The platform in Windows.
Java version is Java 8.
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) to create a `uber-jar` which will have all the dependent classes.

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) is the example to do it.

If you want to try your own solution, then can you please try to add explicit jar names in the [Class-Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath) of your manifest file.

Comment: Adding explicit jar names in the Class-Path of my manifest file is unfortunately exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't want to use maven to solve this problem. I might be naive but there must be an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki, even when we use command line classpath with jars, we have to specify the path. Thus looks like you have to specify the jar paths explicitely.

Comment: what do you use as build tool?